# Nginx invalid URL path prefix .. while sending to client

Tags: nginx

I have the following server settings which work for one URL but seem to fail on another URL.

```
location / {


    proxy_buffers 16 4k;
    proxy_buffer_size 2k;       


    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;

    proxy_pass http://10.4.1.81/;


    # This is used to handle the multiple redirect 301 that the server is doing
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirects;     


}   

location @handle_redirects {
    set $saved_redirect_location '$upstream_http_location';
    proxy_pass $saved_redirect_location;
}
```

When I go to the following URL:

```
https://lfdocs.mohave.gov/bos/0/doc/1652027/Page1.aspx
```

I get the following error from Nginx

```
2020/12/03 19:10:40 [error] 31251#31251: *1 invalid URL prefix in "/bos/CookieCheck.aspx?redirect=%2fbos%2fDocView.aspx%3fdbid%3d0%26id%3d1652027%26page%3d1" while sending to client, client: 10.10.82.151, server: lfdocs.mohave.gov, request: "GET /bos/0/doc/1652027/Page1.aspx HTTP/2.0", host: "lfdocs.mohave.gov"
```

I did some research but I can't seem to figure it out.  Any advice?

Thanks

**Update**

Here is what seems to be the problem the ones that valid are the ones with a valid URL.  When it fails it's because the URL is invalid.

1. Using echo $saved_redirect_location;

   **Success**

   URL:

   https://lfdocs.mohave.gov/Forms/RequestToSpeak

   Return:

   https://10.4.1.81/Forms/RequestToSpeak

   **Fails**:

   URL:

   https://lfdocs.mohave.gov/bos/0/doc/1652027/Page1.aspx

   Returns:

   /bos/CookieCheck.aspx?redirect=%2fbos%2fDocView.aspx%3fdbid%3d0%26id%3d1652027%26page%3d1
2. Using echo http://10.4.1.81$saved_redirect_location;

   **Fails**

   URL:

   https://lfdocs.mohave.gov/Forms/RequestToSpeak

   Return:

   http://10.4.1.81https://10.4.1.81/Forms/RequestToSpeak

   **Success**

   URL:

   https://lfdocs.mohave.gov/bos/0/doc/1652027/Page1.aspx

   Return:

   http://10.4.1.81/bos/CookieCheck.aspx?redirect=%2fbos%2fDocView.aspx%3fdbid%3d0%26id%3d1652027%26page%3d1

using $saved_redirect_location to proxy_pass is there a way to check if the domain exists and if not to add it?

**Update**

My solution was to do the following:

```
   location @handle_redirects {
    set $saved_redirect_location '$upstream_http_location';

    # If IP exists just proxy pass
    if ($saved_redirect_location ~* "10.4.1.81") {
        proxy_pass $saved_redirect_location;
    }

    # If IP doesnt exist append it first
    if ($saved_redirect_location !~* "10.4.1.81") {
        proxy_pass http://10.4.1.81$saved_redirect_location;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Maybe your new location returned after redirect as `Location: /bos/CookieCheck.aspx?redirect=%2fbos%2fDocView.aspx%3fdbid%3d0%26id%3d1652027%26page%3d1` without the scheme or domain name parts? Then you need to use something like `proxy_pass http://10.4.1.81$saved_redirect_location;` instead of `proxy_pass $saved_redirect_location;`

Comment: It is perfectly valid for the Location: to include a partial URL that begins with the path component. So, yes, you do need to deal with this. Also, answers should be posted below as an _answer_, so that people don't think it is part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that ended up working for me.  Thanks, Ivan for the tip.

```
location @handle_redirects {
  set $saved_redirect_location '$upstream_http_location';

  # If IP exists just proxy pass
  if ($saved_redirect_location ~* "10.4.1.81") {
    proxy_pass $saved_redirect_location;
  }

  # If IP doesnt exist append it first
  if ($saved_redirect_location !~* "10.4.1.81") {
    proxy_pass http://10.4.1.81$saved_redirect_location;
  }       
}
```